# Calculus additional condition for mod function to be not differentiable

Tags: calculus

Is there any additional condition for not differentiable of |f(x)|  except f(x)=0 where f(x) takes positive and negative values.

Comment: Assuming that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: If you remove $0$ from the domain then the absolute value function is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

consider f(x) = x^3
now |f(x)| is differentiable at f(x) = 0 which exactly opposes the given condition 
hence there must be some more condition to say the hypothesis is true.

I think the additional condition is f'(x){ derivative of f}must not be equal to zero at the points where f(x)=0